# Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee]

Tags: java, spring, jsf, configuration, portlet

I am developing portlet+jsf

It's my faces-config.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <faces-config version="2.1" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd">

            <application>
                <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
                <navigation-handler>
                    org.springframework.webflow.executor.jsf.FlowNavigationHandler
                </navigation-handler>
                <variable-resolver>
                    org.springframework.web.jsf.DelegatingVariableResolver
                </variable-resolver>
            </application>
            <lifecycle>
                <phase-listener>com.liferay.faces.util.lifecycle.DebugPhaseListener</phase-listener>
                <phase-listener>com.liferay.faces.util.lifecycle.ViewScopePhaseListener</phase-listener>
                <phase-listener>org.springframework.webflow.executor.jsf.FlowPhaseListener</phase-listener>
            </lifecycle>

        </faces-config>
```

When I am trying deploy my portlet, I get following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/context/faces-config.xml]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68) ~[spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85) ~[spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:80) ~[spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.error(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:316) ~[spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1416) ~[spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1409) ~[spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:190) ~[spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:140) ~[spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:111) ~[spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493) ~[spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390) ~[spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334) ~[spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302) ~[spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:255) ~[spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
```

Can anybody help me resolve this problem?

Comment: The webapp's runtime classpath is missing some Spring-specific JARs/dependencies. Which JARs do you have there and how exactly are you building?

Comment: There are spring-beans, spring-context, spring-core, spring-aop, spring-expression, spring-jdbc, spring-tx, spring-web, spring-webmvc, spring-webflow dependencies in my pom.xml file. I use mvn clean install command for building my webapp.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd
```

with

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2‌​_1.xsd"
```

**EDIT:**  Apparently, the version 2.1 had some issues, with getting the `schemaLocation` from former location. It has been fixed. But according to the error, I think that the xml isn't able to find the schema. So you can try replacing it and check if it works. Hope I was of some use.

Comment: Sorry, this answer isn't making much sense. Please explain in technical terms how exactly this problem is caused and how exactly this solution fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue,go to eclipse-java facet uncheck it,click ok then clean build and start server.It should work fine then again go to java facet check it runtime tomcat server then restart server. It worked for me.